# How to form 3 groups and allocate them different district?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, permutations

> At an election three districts are to be canvassed by $10, 15$ and
>   $20$ men respectively. If $45$ men volunteer, in how many ways can
>   they be allotted to the different districts?

Three groups of $10, 15, 20$ can be formed in $\frac{45!}{10! \cdot 15! \cdot 20!}$ ways.

But my question is how do we take care of the situation which gives option of 3 districts to the first group and option of 2 districts to the second group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we have 3 distinct district say $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, and each district needs a different number of people, say $X$ needs 10, $Y$ needs 15 and $Z$ needs 20.

In how many ways can we choose the 10 men to be assigned to $X$ ? Clearly in $C(45,10)$, where $C(n,k)$ represents the binomial coefficient $n!/(k!(n-k)!)$.

Now we are left with $35$ men from which we need to select $15$ for the district $Y$,  and this can be done in $C(35,15)$ ways. Once this is done, the other 20 go to district $Z$.

So in total there are $C(45,10)\cdot C(35,15)$ ways to do this, and this is equal to 
$$
\frac{45!}{10!\cdot 35!}\cdot\frac{35!}{15!\cdot 20!}=\frac{45!}{10!\cdot 15!\cdot 20!}
$$

According to the problem, there is not actually any option for the groups to be assigned to different districts, because the group of 10 people can only go where 10 people are needed, i.e., the first district, the group of 15 people is only needed in second district and the group of 20 people is only needed in the third district.